# how to pass data from dialog box in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

Right now In my Edit page a user can delete section and subsection but I'm thinking about adding confirmation dialog so that a user will not accidentally delete either of them.

I'm not really sure how I can pass the data between confirmation dialog component and Edit Page component.

The project is not gonna run on on Stackblitz but I have uploaded those two component in here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztepf6?file=Edit Component/EditComponent.ts

so  I will be really appreciated if anybody can check it out and able to help me. thanks

Edit Component.TS

```
this is how I open Comfirmation Dialog

  openSection() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        isSection: true, isSubsection: false
      },
    }
    );
  }
  openSubsection(){
      this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        data: {
          isSubsection: true, isSection: false
        },
      });
  }

//This is how I'm deleting right now without confirmation Dialog
  delete(sec) {
    if (this.isSection) {
      this.HelpService.deleteHelpSection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
        const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.id);
        this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id)
        if (~index) {
          this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
            this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id);
          })
        }
      })
    } if (this.isSubsection) {
      this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
        const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.parentId);
        if (~index) {
          this.mappedSections[index].subSections = this.mappedSections[index].subSections.filter((subsection) => subsection.id != sec.id)
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

subscribe for the result from the modal.

```
 openSection() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        isSection: true, isSubsection: false
      },
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
      if(result){
         this.delete(sec)
      }
    });
  }
```

from the modal component pass the data

```
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
```

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>
  ) {}  
  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
```

check this working sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pd7vt6?file=src/app/dialog-elements-example.ts

Comment: Hi thank you for this but I'm not sure where this.fromPage and this.fromDialog coming from because I'm getting an error on those two. :(

Comment: that fromPage and fromDialog are variables of that ConfirmDialogComponent.